# Gunicorn doesn't recognise Wagtail CMS

Tags: python, django, debian, gunicorn, wagtail

I am migrating my website from Mezzanine to [Wagtail](http://wagtail.io) running on a Debian machine using virtualenv, but after setting up Wagtail, user permissions and source when I run `# gunicorn_django` in the wagtail folder I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/userblog/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/user/userblog/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 106, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/user/userblog/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/user/userblog/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/djangoapp.py", line 102, in load
    make_default_env(self.cfg)
  File "/home/user/userblog/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/djangoapp.py", line 62, in make_default_env
    raise RuntimeError("django project not found")
RuntimeError: django project not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/userblog/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/user/userblog/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 106, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/user/userblog/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/user/userblog/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/djangoapp.py", line 102, in load
    make_default_env(self.cfg)
  File "/home/user/userblog/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/djangoapp.py", line 62, in make_default_env
    raise RuntimeError("django project not found")
RuntimeError: django project not found
2014-06-09 10:41:27 [2774] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 2774)
2014-06-09 10:41:28 [2769] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2014-06-09 10:41:28 [2769] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

As far as I know I did nothing different from my mezzanine setup, and I know Wagtail is also Django based. Anyone know where the problem could be?

Answer (score 4):

gunicorn_django is [deprecated since Gunicorn 18](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/18.0/news.html#id1). If possible, you should use the WSGI interface with Django. See the [Django with Gunicorn docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/).

However, that said, when using gunicorn_django where the settings aren't in settings.py but instead in a module you should be able to get it to work by specifying the dotted path to the relevant settings file - e.g. in your `mywagtailproject` folder, the `mywagtailproject/settings/production.py` file (note that your mywagtailproject folder will have an identically named mywagtailproject sub-folder):

```
gunicorn_django --settings=mywagtailproject.settings.production --pythonpath=/pathto/mywagtailproject
```

You may or may not need to set the `--pythonpath` argument.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm beginning to understand the problem, however how would I get this project on my pythonpath? I get the error `No module named wagtaildemo.settings.production ` now and I have no idea how to let it know where to look for this data. The production.py file does exists in the `pathto/wagtail/wagtail/settings/` folder.

Comment: You'll have a problem if you've called your project 'wagtail', as that's going to confuse python's path searching because the Wagtail app (installed in sites-packages with pip) is called wagtail. You want your project to be called something else - such as wagtaildemo. In which case there'll need to be a same-named sub-directory containing the settings directory. I.e. if the path to production.py is `pathto/wagtaildemo/wagtaildemo/settings` then python will find the module `wagtaildemo.setting.production`.

Comment: It is not named wagtail, perhaps a bad example to use, it is indeed named wagtaildemo (the folder) but does the folder imply the name of the project? or is there some variable somewhere to set the project name? Thanks!

Comment: The name of folder is the name of project. When the project is started a subdirectory of the same name is created for the settings, urls and wsgi files.

If your project is at `/pathto/wagtaildemo`, you should have `/pathto/wagtaildemo/wagtaildemo/settings/production.py`. If so, this should work when run from `/pathto/wagtaildemo`:

    `gunicorn_django --settings=wagtaildemo.settings.production --pythonpath=/pathto/wagtaildemo`

If it doesn't it's hard to say what might be the issue with your particular setup - there isn't anything Wagtail specific about the Gunicorn setup.

Comment: Try running it under Gunicorn as a WSGI application. If/when you upgrade to Gunicorn >=18 you'll find you can use `gunicorn_django` anymore anyway.

This is the equivalent for running the dev.py settings:

    `gunicorn wagtaildemo.wsgi:application`

To run Wagtail using production settings you can create another wsgi file that uses production.py:

    `cp wagtaildemo/wsgi.py wagtaildemo/wsgi_production.py ;
    perl -pi -e"s/(wagtaildemo.settings)/\1.production/"  wagtaildemo/wsgi_production.py`

And then run gunicorn with:

    `gunicorn wagtaildemo.wsgi_production:application`